# Why can I not find HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369784(v=vs.85).aspx

I am trying to find this location in the windows 7 registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer

I am very curious as to why I cannot find this. Could someone provide me with an explanation as to why? Also is there any major differences you could point out in a paragraph between the registrys of Windows 7 and XP.

Comment: I remember that Windows 7 Regedit names HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE as HKLM. Also, there's no real need for a leaf to exist, if nothing uses it. AFAIK there are no major differences in the structures of the registry between those versions, apart from the keys needed to make the OS work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suspected, that particular key doesn't exist unless the Windows Installer is being managed by AD domain based Group Policy through the GPMC or local Group Policy through the use of the local Group Policy editor.